Datasets for inverse heat transfer problems
I was wondering if there is an available, real-life known inverse heat transfer problem dataset to benchmark oneselfs algorithm, as in MNIST for deep learning. Talking about... (well in this case I just like bayesian-like approaches)
https://doi.org/10.1080/01457632.2011.525137
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijheatmasstransfer.2004.02.028
or thermal diffusivity reconstruction which I like pretty much. I would feel pretty satisfied if I was not creating the problems I'm solving hehe but if I could benchmark against someone. Just want to feel I'm doing something useful.
Thanks for reading!

Why not make one yourself and make it publicly available? See related work: https://open.bu.edu/bitstream/2144/39813/1/MechanicalMNIST_2_20.pdf

@NNN I could do in what I imagine it is a good inverse problem but I'd really like to know what are the realistic setups: is the noise homoskedastic, white, uncorrelated, how far apart are observations, geometry of the problem, proper priors over thermal conductivity... I can make this stuff up but I'd really like to know what engineers face, would really like to work in realistic numerical scales and numerical error
